# extract number between characters and order them

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hey I am thinking about a solution for my problem for hours now. I've searched the web, too and was able to find some approaches but none of them does work for my problem.

I have one cell with data that appears like this:

```
(Monday@100%[00:00-24:00]);(Tuesday@100%[00:00-24:00]);(Wednesday@100%[00:00-24:00]);(Thursday@100%[00:00-24:00]);(Friday@100%[00:00-24:00]);(Saturday@100%[00:00-24:00]);(Sunday@100%[00:00-24:00])
```

The problem is, that this string is not consistent. It could also look like this:

```
(Monday@125%[00:00-04:00]);(Monday@90%[04:00-08:00]);(Monday@90%[08:00-12:00]);(Monday@115%[12:00-16:00]);(Monday@120%[16:00-20:00]);(Monday@115%[20:00-24:00]);(Tuesday@125%[00:00-04:00]);(Tuesday@90%[04:00-08:00]);(Tuesday@90%[08:00-12:00]);(Tuesday@115%[12:00-16:00]);(Tuesday@120%[16:00-20:00]);(Tuesday@115%[20:00-24:00]);(Wednesday@125%[00:00-04:00]);(Wednesday@90%[04:00-08:00]);(Wednesday@90%[08:00-12:00]);(Wednesday@115%[12:00-16:00]);(Wednesday@120%[16:00-20:00]);(Wednesday@115%[20:00-24:00]);(Thursday@125%[00:00-04:00]);(Thursday@90%[04:00-08:00]);(Thursday@90%[08:00-12:00]);(Thursday@115%[12:00-16:00]);(Thursday@120%[16:00-20:00]);(Thursday@115%[20:00-24:00]);(Friday@125%[00:00-04:00]);(Friday@90%[04:00-08:00]);(Friday@90%[08:00-12:00]);(Friday@115%[12:00-16:00]);(Friday@120%[16:00-20:00]);(Friday@115%[20:00-24:00]);(Saturday@125%[00:00-04:00]);(Saturday@90%[04:00-08:00]);(Saturday@90%[08:00-12:00]);(Saturday@115%[12:00-16:00]);(Saturday@120%[16:00-20:00]);(Saturday@115%[20:00-24:00]);(Sunday@125%[00:00-04:00]);(Sunday@90%[04:00-08:00]);(Sunday@90%[08:00-12:00]);(Sunday@115%[12:00-16:00]);(Sunday@120%[16:00-20:00]);(Sunday@115%[20:00-24:00])
```

The structure of the string is

- You have a day of the week followed by an "@"
- after the `at` (@) you have a number that can be between 0 and 999
- after that you have a time of the day in brackets []
- You can have up to 6 different time frames of one day (not more, but less)
- each time frame cluster is separated by ; and within normal brackets ()

So this is my starting position. What I want is to extract the numbers between @ and % and list them chronologically (Monday to Sunday, hours of the day).

I was able to extract the number between @ and % for each day of the week with this formula

```
=MID(B3;SEARCH("Monday@";B3)+7;SEARCH("%";B3)-SEARCH("Monday@";B3)-7)
```

But this only works if each day of the week is mentioned only ones.

I am out of ideas of how I could get it to work when having more time frames per day. Appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Ramon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Text-to-Columns** feature of excel, with `)` as a delimiter. Than transpose the columns into rows to get something like this:

```
(Monday@125%[00:00-04:00]
;(Monday@90%[04:00-08:00]
;(Monday@90%[08:00-12:00]
;(Monday@115%[12:00-16:00]
;(Monday@120%[16:00-20:00]
...
;(Sunday@115%[20:00-24:00]
```

Then apply formulas.

**Edit:**

Using just `Find` and `Mid` you can achieve this:
[image]

The idea behind find and mid is always the same.
Ex. for finding `(` is `=FIND("(";[Text])`.
Ex. for extracting `Day` is `=MID([Text];[@[Pos(]]+1;[@[Pos'@]]-[@[Pos(]]-1)`

Comment: That was a good solution as well. Wrote a macro which is doing TextToColumn automatically and list all necessary data the way I need it. Thanks for all your help guys! I don't know how to mark this as solved (if even possible) but it is for me ;-)

Comment: Glad it helped. By accepting an answer, you show others, that you have the solution you need. You already did this. To learn more visit [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Try an set of iterative searches, where the next search starts at the position found for the previous result. ie:

in cell B6 put `=SEARCH("]",$B$3,B5+1)`

in cell C6 put `=MID($B$3,SEARCH("(",$B$3,B5+1)+1,SEARCH("@",$B$3,B5+1)-SEARCH("(",$B$3,B5+1)-1)`

in cell D6 put `=MID($B$3,SEARCH("[",$B$3,B5+1)+1,SEARCH("]",$B$3,B5+1)-SEARCH("[",$B$3,B5+1)-1)`

in cell E6 put `=MID($B$3,SEARCH("@",$B$3,B5+1)+1,SEARCH("%",$B$3,B5+1)-SEARCH("@",$B$3,B5+1)-1)`

(Note that B5 needs to be empty (or 0) for this to start correctly)

You can then fill down as far as needed to pick up each term. If they are out of order, then you can order on column D then C (the time then the day).

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started.

```
Sub Extractor()
    Dim data() As String, i As Integer, rw As Integer

    rw = 3
    data = Split(Range("A1"), ";")

    For i = 0 To UBound(data)
        Range("A" & rw) = VBA.Mid$(data(i), 2, InStr(1, data(i), "@") - 2) 'Day
        Range("B" & rw) = VBA.Mid$(data(i), InStr(1, data(i), "@") + 1, InStr(1, data(i), "%") - InStr(1, data(i), "@") - 1) '% number
        Range("C" & rw) = VBA.Mid$(data(i), InStr(1, data(i), "[") + 1, InStr(1, data(i), "]") - InStr(1, data(i), "[") - 1) 'Time
        rw = rw + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Notes:

1. Assumes your string is in `A1`
2. Prints your data in columns A, B, and C starting in `row 3`

Comment: Wow this is awesome. It did work really well. Although it is a bit slow, especially with bigger data. 
Anyway, it is a first solution. Thanks so much!
As I am not that familiar with vba, could you explain what it does and how it works? It might help me to improve the performance.

Comment: Glad it worked! It may be a bit slow with lots of data. You could factor out some of the `InStr` functions as they calculate the same result twice. That may help speed it up.

Comment: Also to speed things up a bit, you can use `Range("A" & rw).Value2` and so on, instead of `Range("A" & rw).Value` which is default. For more info see this excelent article [Writing efficient VBA UDFs (Part 1) – It ain’t what you do it’s the way that you do it](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-1/)